# how to save the result of a query in a int variable?

Tags: android, sqlite

Hi I develop an application on android ADT. I am using sqlite to validate the registration. When the user registers are saved in a database and the database I want to check if a record already exists for the activity log is not open. This is the code that I used,  not shown error but does not function.

```
   public void onContinue(){
   AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this,
            "pacman", null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase bd = admin.getReadableDatabase();
int total;
Cursor c = bd.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM numeros", null);
    total = c.getCount();
    Intent nu;


    if(total == 1){
        nu = new Intent (this, ContactListActivity.class);
        startActivity(nu);

    } 
    else
         nu=new Intent(this, Bienvenido.class);
startActivity(nu);
 finish();
 }
```

Comment: You should definitely show your Stacktrace, please

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "does not function"? What do you expect to happen? What actually happens? What variables have an unexpected value?

Comment: I say it does not work because there is already a valid registration. After saving the log verified that this saving and save it, but when I run the application detects unsaved enters the record again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT2:

I believe you wanted to start 1 activity only but when `(total == 1)` you are starting 2.

You should change

```
if(total == 1){
    nu = new Intent (this, ContactListActivity.class);
    startActivity(nu);

} 
else
     nu=new Intent(this, Bienvenido.class);
startActivity(nu);
```

To

```
if(total == 1)
    nu = new Intent (this, ContactListActivity.class);
else
    nu = new Intent(this, Bienvenido.class);

startActivity(nu);
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @CL Well maybe the OP should have made his question more clear as it seems you didn't understand it either.

Comment: This answer is just an optimization; it cannot fix the problem, whatever it might be.

Comment: @CL Ah. You're right. Didn't think you can call getCount before moveToFirst.. Silly me :)